# why constant size of struct despite having a vector of int

Tags: c++, struct, sizeof

I have defined a struct which contains a vector of integer. Then I insert 10 integers in the vector and check for the size of struct. But I see no difference.

Here is my code:

```
struct data
{
  vector<int> points;
}

int main()
{
  data d;
  cout << sizeof(d) << endl;
  for (int i=0; i< 10; ++i)
    d.points.push_back(i)
  cout << sizeof(d) << endl;
```

In both the cases I am getting the same result : **16**

Why is it so? Shouldn't the size of struct grow?

Comment: A struct is a pointer a memory location, it will always have the same size. You would need to size_of the contents to get the sum of the member data.

Comment: hint: sizeof is a compile time construct in C++

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator is a compile time operation that gives you the size of the data structure used to maintain the container, not including the size of the stored elements.

While this might not seem too intuitive at first, consider that when you use a `std::vector` you are using a small amount of *local* storage (where the `std::vector` is created) which maintains pointers to a different region holding the actual data. When the vector grows the data block will grow, but the control structure is still the same.

The fact that `sizeof` will not change during it's lifetime is important, as it is the only way of making sure that the compiler can allocate space for `points` inside `data` without interfering with other possible members:

```
struct data2 {
  int x;
  std::vector<int> points;
  int y;
};
```

If the size of the object (`std::vector` in this case) was allowed to grow it would expand over the space allocated for `y` breaking any code that might depend on its location:

```
data2 d;
int *p = &d.y;
d.points.push_back(5);
// does `p` still point to `&d.y`? or did the vector grow over `y`?
```

Comment: A related issue is that while arrays aren't used as much in C++ as in "old" C, it's legal to store any definable type, including vectors, in an array, and all items of an array must have the same size.

Answer (score 10):

A `vector` will store its elements in dynamically allocated memory (on the heap). Internally, this *might* be represented as:

```
T* elems;        // Pointer memory.
size_t count;    // Current number of elements.
size_t capacity; // Total number of elements that can be held.
```

so the `sizeof(std::vector)` is unaffected by the number of elements it contains as it calculating the `sizeof` its contained members (in this simple example roughly `sizeof(T*) + (2 * sizeof(size_t))`).

Comment: The common approach is three pointers, while the italics in *might* indicate that you are aware that the implementation could use pointers rather than integers, I still think it is important to mention that there is a third data element needed: the capacity of the vector, which is used to determine when the vector needs to grow. Additionally there is an allocator, but that is usually optimized out (Empty Base Optimization)

Comment: You're right in general, but... I don't think you can implement an `std::vector` without at least three pointers and/or `size_t`.  (All of the implementations I've seen have used three pointers.  Or more, when debugging is turned on.)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas (and @JamesKanze), agreed. Was just condsidering that when you commented. Will update. Thanks.

Comment: Someone might also mention the requirement that `sizeof` be a compile time constant.  Which means that it cannot possibly change according to the (dynamic) size of the vector.  (`std::array`, of course, is another kettle of fish.)