# c++ vector inside a structure

Tags: c++, vector, realloc

I've got a doubt about using `std::vector`.
If I got a structure with a  `std::vector` object with nondefined space in the memory, if it need to be reallocate (the `std::vector`), is the structure also reallocated? or only the `std::vector`?

For example:

```
struct cluster{
    int a;
    int b;
    struct cluster* parent;
    vector<struct cluster> children;
}

struct cluster obj = {2,1,...};

struct cluster *pobj = &obj;

for(int i = 0; i < 100 ; i ++){
    children.push_back(i); //The capacity will be increased progressly, no?
}
```

So, the question is: is `pobj==&obj` at the end of `for` loop? Or is `obj` reallocated because of the reallocation of child `std::vector` object?

I hope I explained my doubt.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528855/why-constant-size-of-struct-despite-having-a-vector-of-int

Comment: The question is moot. This is undefined behaviour. You cannot instantiate an `std::vector` with an incomplete type, which `cluster` is at the point there `childs` is declared.

Comment: Oh srry, I can't understand what are you trying to say. I'm using this structure to look over a segmented image, for a color tracking algorithm. After the image is segmented, it's codified in RLE. finally I got some cluster of pixels codified in RLE that need to be "parented". Initially I used an unique parent and child for every structure, but then I realized that will be some troubles with overlaped clusters...

Comment: I meant... for example if I've got a "V" on the image, the vertex need to have two parents. Then I changed the algorithm and decided that every run of RLE will be a child of the first run of the object... So that, I need a vector inside the structure 'cause I didn't know the number of childs. I hope it helps to understand the doubt.

Comment: As @juanchopanza says, it is undefined behavior to declare a vector of an incomplete type.  I doesn't compile with the compiler and options I usually use for my own work (and the committee will probably require it to be an error in the future).

Comment: Also: you don't need the `struct` everywhere.  Just when you define the class.  (Also, in English, the plural of "child" is "children", not "childs".  English is even less coherent than C++.)

Comment: You could have a look at `boost::container`'s [containers of incomplete types](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/container/containers_of_incomplete_types.html). This has a `vector` class that allows you to do this nesting.

Comment: @juanchopanza Interesting.  It's true that with the usual implementation of `std::vector`, there isn't really a need to ban incomplete types in the data declaration; you don't need it until a member function is called.

Comment: @JamesKanze Right, and I wondered if that would mean that in a future standard this restriction would be relaxed, but IIRC it is not being considered.

Comment: @juanchopanza I've not heard anything about it either.  Some things were relaxed (e.g. Assignable is no longer required for node based containers), but the only templates where an incomplete type is acceptable are `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @juanchopanza & JamesKanze Thanks for everything, It's obvious that I'm a newbie at c++ and I've so much to learn (And sorry If I make some English mistakes). I'm going to change the code. Maybe, I needn't the vector inside the structure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, your `obj` variable is never reallocated because members inside it change. The vector have its own pointers to its data, and handles all its own allocations and reallocations internally.

Think about it this way: Normally local variables (including full structures and arrays) are put on the stack of the current function. The compiler accesses these variables through an offset from a base address. If the compiler (or system) suddenly started to move variables around in memory it would complicate variable access *considerably* and also affect runtime speed and efficiency of your program quite a lot. So local variables are on the stack, and stays where they were put by the compiler. Data allocated on the heap (like the data inside a `std::vector`) can be easily moved around since all that has to be updated in the pointer to the data, and like I said before it's all handled internally in the vector object so nothing you would notice anyway.

Comment: While your explication is good as far as it goes, you really should point out that as written, his code has undefined behavior.  (It doesn't compile with g++ if you use the usual `-D_GLIBCXX_CONCEPT_CHECKS`.)